# Pandas and groupby count the number of matches in two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to count the number of matches after a groupby in a pandas dataframe.

```
claim   event   material1   material2
A       X       M1          M2
A       X       M2          M3
A       X       M3          M0
A       X       M4          M4
A       Y       M5          M5
A       Y       M6          M0
B       Z       M7          M0
B       Z       M8          M0
```

First, I group by the pair claim event and for each of these groups I want to count the number of matches between the columns material1 and material 2

For the group by, I have `grouped = df.groupby(['claim', 'event'])` but then I don't know how to compare the two new columns.

It should return the following dataframe :

```
claim   event   matches
A       X       3          
A       Y       1          
B       Z       0
```

Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for compare columns and groupby by columns with aggregate `sum`, last cast to `int` and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
a = (df['material1'].isin(df['material2']))
df = a.groupby([df['claim'], df['event']]).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='matches')
```

Solution with assign to new column:

```
df['matches'] = df['material1'].isin(df['material2']).astype(int)
df = df.groupby(['claim', 'event'])['matches'].sum().reset_index()
```

Solutions by @Wen, thank you:

```
df['matches'] = df['material1'].isin(df['material2']).astype(int)
df = df.groupby(['claim', 'event'], as_index=False)['matches'].sum()
```

I think it should be slowier in larger `DataFrame`s:

```
df = (df.groupby(['claim', 'event'])
                  .apply(lambda x : x['material1'].isin(x['material2']).astype(int).sum())
                  .reset_index(name='matches'))
```

---

```
print (df)
  claim event  matches
0     A     X        3
1     A     Y        1
2     B     Z        0
```

Comment: Maybe `df.groupby(['claim', 'event'],as_index=False)['matches'].sum()`

Comment: Also for getting the match column should it be `df['matches']=df.groupby(['claim', 'event']).apply(lambda x : x['material1'].isin(x['material2']).astype(int)).values` ?

Comment: @Wen - Yes, it is possible, but slowier.

Comment: Yes, I repair it.